# Error while trying to install pycurl in Synology NAS

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycurl, synology

I am using synology NAS and python(installed 2.7, 3.5)

when I try to install via PIP, I encounter this error message.

(the first time, I met curl-config not found error.
but now with several entware packages, I met with the message below)

```
----------

python3 -m pip install pycurl
Collecting pycurl
  Using cached pycurl-7.43.0.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: pycurl
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pycurl ... error
  Complete output from command /usr/local/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-79dqoc3v/pycurl/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmpa8e0oiyqpip-wheel- --python-tag cp35:
  Using curl-config (libcurl 7.55.0)
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/curl
  copying python/curl/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/curl
  running build_ext
  building 'pycurl' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/src
  /usr/local/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-ccache-gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DSYNO_FIX_FLAG_BUG -DOPENSSL_NO_SSL3 -DOPENSSL_NO_SSL2 -DSYNOPLAT_F_X86_64 -O2 -include /usr/syno/include/platformconfig.h -DSYNO_ENVIRONMENT -DBUILD_ARCH=64 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -g -DSDK_VER_MIN_REQUIRED=600 -pipe -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Wformat-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O2 -Wno-unused-result -fPIC -DPYCURL_VERSION="7.43.0" -DHAVE_CURL_SSL=1 -I/opt/include -I/volume1/@appstore/py3k/usr/local/include/python3.5m -c src/docstrings.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/src/docstrings.o
  unable to execute '/usr/local/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-ccache-gcc': No such file or directory
  error: command '/usr/local/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-ccache-gcc' failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for pycurl
  Running setup.py clean for pycurl
Failed to build pycurl
Installing collected packages: pycurl
  Running setup.py install for pycurl ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/local/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-79dqoc3v/pycurl/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-q_rurvzr-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    Using curl-config (libcurl 7.55.0)
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/curl
    copying python/curl/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/curl
    running build_ext
    building 'pycurl' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/src
    /usr/local/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-ccache-gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DSYNO_FIX_FLAG_BUG -DOPENSSL_NO_SSL3 -DOPENSSL_NO_SSL2 -DSYNOPLAT_F_X86_64 -O2 -include /usr/syno/include/platformconfig.h -DSYNO_ENVIRONMENT -DBUILD_ARCH=64 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -g -DSDK_VER_MIN_REQUIRED=600 -pipe -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Wformat-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O2 -Wno-unused-result -fPIC -DPYCURL_VERSION="7.43.0" -DHAVE_CURL_SSL=1 -I/opt/include -I/volume1/@appstore/py3k/usr/local/include/python3.5m -c src/docstrings.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/src/docstrings.o
    unable to execute '/usr/local/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-ccache-gcc': No such file or directory
    error: command '/usr/local/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-ccache-gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/local/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-79dqoc3v/pycurl/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-q_rurvzr-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-79dqoc3v/pycurl/
```

Comment: Try installing using the .whl file from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pycurl)

Comment: I already tried it with .whl file but it also show error like below
<br>
wheel.tool.WheelError: pycurl-7.43.0-cp35-none-win32.whl is not compatible with this Python. --force to install anyway.
(I am using python3.5)

Comment: I also tried with your recommendation(pycurl-7.43.0-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl) but it doesn't work neither

Comment: If I use 'force' option with it, there is no response

Comment: Make sure you are downloading the correct .whl file for your system. Do you have 32 or 64 bit Python? Also, you have 2 different Python versions on your PC, so make sure `pip` is trying to install `pycurl` for the correct version of Python.

Comment: Based on your comment I tried other things. but it doesn't work too.

Comment: I checked my python with platform.architecurture() ==> 64bit, and I tried pycurl-7.43.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl but it doesn't work

Comment: and I am using "python3 -m" command because there are two version.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem too with by Synology DS415+. The only difference is that I tried to install netdisco.
I found that setting the CC environmental variable to the actual location of gcc compiler in advance helped

# export CC=/opt/bin/gcc